# How to display file picker controller UI using Dropbox SDK for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an iPhone application using Dropbox functionality.

What I need is to display a custom view controller allowing users to browse their own Dropbox and selecting a file. This view controller should look similar to the official iPhone Dropbox app where you can navigate among the folders and choose a file.

I know I can implement this view controller by myself using the Dropbox SDK.. but I hoped to find some code already doing it and publicly shared.

Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 1):

I know DZDocumentsPickerController, that I am using, but it's quite complicated to integrate.

https://github.com/DZen-Interaktiv/DZDocumentsPickerController

Comment: I already tried it but it didn't compile on XCode... Eventually, I have implemented it by myself using Dropbox API. Thanks anyway.

Comment: DZDocumentPicker is not very well done. 
I am trying to make a photo picker where the user could select from photo library or dropbox. 
Have you managed to develop a good navigation controller system ?

Comment: Joshua > I can't do whatever I want with DZDocumentPicker. Do you mind sharing your code to browse dropbox with a navigation controller ?